# Загрузка ресурсов веб-приложения в кэш

Tags: javascript, xhr

Привет.
Для того, чтобы пользователь видел красивый прелоадер загрузки сайта, я использую следующий код:

```
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 //path -- это переменная с адресом файла на сервере. Список path так же получаю с сервера.
 //задаю переменную path в xhr, для доступа из событий onload, error, ...
 xhr.path = path.toString();
 xhr.open("GET", 'https://web.lotus-app.ru/' + path, true);
 xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
 xhr.responseType = "blob";
 //задаю onload, progress, abort, errror, timeout
 xhr.send();
```

Все файлы (js, svg, css, tff, html) с сайта грузятся, но когда они понадобятся браузеру, они грузятся заново, т.е. вот эта вся предзагрузка ничего не дает. Как правильно это делать?

*Дополнение*

Обнаружил, что файлы, которые нужны браузеру, имеют type: stylesheet, png, svg+xml, script, document; а те, что гружу я: xhr...

[image: type]

Comment: посмотрите на [Service Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API). они пока еще не везде поддерживаются, но делают то, что вам нужно.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman "Не везде" -- это насколько?_) p.s. А, все, вижу...

Comment: перейдите по ссылке и посмотрите

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас в консоли браузера отключено кэширование - в таком случае всегда запросы будут идти на сервер.

Comment: Блин, во я затупил. Спасибо, бро!)